# Spray, ScalaTest and HTTP services: could not find implicit value for parameter ta:

Tags: scala, spray, scalatest

I am, again, struggling with spray and cannot set up a test correctly. I looked at the similar question [spray-testkit: could not find implicit value for parameter ta:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28686789/spray-testkit-could-not-find-implicit-value-for-parameter-ta) and the [official spray template](https://github.com/spray/spray-template) and cannot figure out what I am missing and/or doing wrong.

I have a very simple service:

```
trait SimpleService extends HttpService{

  val fooRoute = path("foo") {
    get {
      complete("bar")
    }
  }
}
```

And I have a very simple test:

```
class SimpleServiceTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers with SimpleService with ScalatestRouteTest {

  override implicit def actorRefFactory: ActorRefFactory = system

  "The service" should "return OK status when getting /foo" in {
    Get("/foo") ~> fooRoute ~> check {
      status should be(OK)
    }
  }
}
```

when I try to compile this, I get the following error:

```
Error:(17, 17) could not find implicit value for parameter ta: SimpleServiceTest.this.TildeArrow[spray.routing.RequestContext,Unit]
Get("/foo") ~> fooRoute ~> check {
            ^
```

Can anyone help me and tell me what I am missing? I do not find anything unusual, and I am close to evaluating Play instead of spray.

Answer (score 0):

You should mixin `ScalatestRouteTest` before `SimpleService`, like so:

```
class SimpleServiceTest extends ScalatestRouteTest with FlatSpec with Matchers with SimpleService
```

Another possible solution is to add the following lines to where your test throws the Implicit not found:

```
implicitly[spray.testkit.RouteTestTimeout] 
implicitly[spray.routing.RoutingSettings] 
implicitly[spray.util.LoggingContext]
```

See which line throws, and provide the implicit for that type.

Comment: `FlatSpec` needs to be the first because it is not a trait, but I just did exactly this and am getting the same error.

Comment: I finally gave up on this and switched to Play.

Answer (score -1):

The ScalatestRouteTest already provides an implicit ActorySystem. Remove the **"implicit"** modifier from your actorRefFactory method and the test should get executed.

this solve this problem for my code

[Spray.io: Can't compile test spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941358/spray-io-cant-compile-test-spec)